# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in Express.js with jsonwebtoken

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-jwt

i follow the explanation about JWT in expressjs, ( i'm newbie in javascript ), i follow all instruction but i've got error in execute in node :

```
jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN as string , (err: any, user: any) => { 
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Here the complete code :

```
const express = require ('express');
const jwt = require ('jsonwebtoken');
const env = require ('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

let port = 3400;
function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  // Gather the jwt access token from the request header
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
  if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401) // if there isn't any token

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN as string , (err: any, user: any) => {
    console.log(err)
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403)
    req.user = user
    next() // pass the execution off to whatever request the client intended
  })
}
app.get('/api/userOrders', authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
    console.log(token);
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Serve on http://localhost:${port}`))
```

I dont know how to manage this error, need some advice from people here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you might be using TypeScript syntax in JS. My suggestion is to modify this line like that: `jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN.toString() , (err, user) => { `